# using one feign client to call multiple endpoints with different authentication

Tags: spring-boot, rest, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication, openfeign

I am trying to use **same** feign client to call/POST **different** endpoints (endpoint1, endpoint 2 etc) with below (payload structure is same. One can assume that number of endpoint would continue to remain 3 [say] for the deployed app);

- Endpoint 1 - Authentication Mechanism - OAuth2
- Endpoint 2 - Authentication Mechanism - Basic Auth
- Endpoint 3 - Authentication Mechanism - OAuth2 (different client id/secret/okta)

so far only able to successfully  implement calling "endpoint1" with https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-feign-oauth-token as reference, but facing challenges in extending it to support different calls dynamically based on "input", using single feign client. Any help/suggestion is appreciated?

Using Spring Boot 2.7.X and JDK 11.

Comment: NOTE : that number of customers(endpoints) can differ by env (dev, qa etc), but for an env, we will have a fixed identified set with their own auth

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by passing a headerMap containing authorization (Basic, Digest or OAuth2) like this:

```
@FeignClient(name = "dummy", url = "empty")
public interface Client {

    @PostMapping
    void call(URI baseUri, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headerMap, @RequestBody RequestBody requestBody);
}
```

In your service you can create your custom headerMap:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Authorization", <BASIC or other authorization>);
client.call(new URI("http://localhost:8080/endpoint"), headers, requestBody);
```